# Why I need that field like that

Tags: scala

```
case class AlertWindowDto(id: String)

protected val InitialWindowPeriodOneOnPeak = AlertWindowDto(ValidId)

protected val ValidId = "someSite"
```

I saw these there lines in different different classes. just I put together for understanding.

In general, If i am creating an dummy or some object of Class, then I give some value or null or empty string. What is the need of creating another field ValidId and assign some value and assign that field to final object.

is there any benefit, or anything help in test cases.

could you please help me.

Comment: Just imagine a case where this `someSite` string is supposed to be used at multiple locations in your code. Now this approach brings you 2 advantages. 1. It saves you from typos 2. if you need to changes this string due to some reason, you just have to change it once.

Comment: And then there is another reason which has to do with how strings are treated by jvm.

Comment: you should  check magic strings/numbers, it's not good to use directly in code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string

Answer (score 3):

Imagine this:

```
protected val InitialWindowPeriodOneOnPeak = AlertWindowDto("someSite")
```

Does it convey the information that `"someSite"` is a valid id for an alert window?

This is a trivial example, but the general idea is that sometimes breaking down expressions and assigning names to them is great for expressing meaning.

I would also add that the more this naming information is in the types, the better. For instance, here's another way of achieving the same result, without using a variable name.

```
case class ValidId(value: String) extends AnyVal
case class AlertWindowDto(id: ValidId)
protected val InitialWindowPeriodOneOnPeak = AlertWindowDto(ValidId("someSite"))
```

Same information, but the "valid id" information is now stored in the type system.